# Change class for active menu item with php

Tags: php, css, function, menu

I am trying to change the class of an active element in my menu with php, but I am having trouble when using "?side=testpage" as URL

I'm typing the href in php to get the pages opened in the correct div according to my index where this code is included.

The whole code is:

```
<?php 
    function echo_Active_Tab ($requestUri){
        $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

        if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
            echo 'class="active"';
    }
?>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand"<?php echo "href='?side=mainpage'>Økonomiprogrammet</a>"; ?>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li <?=echo_Active_Tab("mainpage")?>><?php echo "<a href='?side=mainpage.php'>Startside</a>"; ?></li>
      <li <?=echo_Active_Tab("overview")?>><?php echo "<a href='?side=overview'>Oversikten</a>"; ?> </li>
      <li <?=echo_Active_Tab("invoice")?>><?php echo "<a href='?side=invoice'>Fakturaer</a>"; ?></li>
      <li <?=echo_Active_Tab("expences")?>><?php echo "<a href='?side=expences'>Utgifter</a>"; ?></li>
    </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Søk</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone spot the error in my code?

EDIT: Don't mind the wrong function name, fixed and edited. The code doesn't do as I'd hoped.

Comment: echoActive("expences") =>echo_Active_Tab("expences")

Comment: This question is simple oversight by poster and does not offer continued value.